# How do I pass a CSharpScript variable a value or object instance before I run it?

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn, csharpscript

Using `CSharpScript`, is there a way I can pass a variable a value or object instance before the script is run?

it seems like using `StateScript` will allow me to set a script variable using the following.

```
ScriptState state;
state.GetVariable("a").Value = 4;
```

In order to get a ScriptState, you have to run a script. Ideally Id like to assign a variable a value or pass an instance of an object before I compile it.

Alternately, is there another way I can pass arguments to a C# script before it is run?

Thanks in advance